# Как преобразовать объект в массив?

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго дня. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно превратить обьект в массив:

```
   {
        "71": {
            "id": "71",
            "price": "12000",
            "weight": "25кг",
            "description": "Используется в качестве умягчителя воды, хелатирующего агента и компонента моющих составов",
            "title": " Хеласин",
            "img": "/upload/iblock/19c/ydj1jqm41n834xh1xcczffrfh9uqlhyd.jpg",
            "priceCount": 1
        },
  "72": {
            "id": "72",
            "price": "12000",
            "weight": "25кг",
            "description": "Используется в качестве умягчителя воды, хелатирующего агента и компонента моющих составов",
            "title": " Хеласин",
            "img": "/upload/iblock/19c/ydj1jqm41n834xh1xcczffrfh9uqlhyd.jpg",
            "priceCount": 1
        }
    }



Ожидаемый результат:
  [
        "71": {
            "id": "71",
            "price": "12000",
            "weight": "25кг",
            "description": "Используется в качестве умягчителя воды, хелатирующего агента и компонента моющих составов",
            "title": " Хеласин",
            "img": "/upload/iblock/19c/ydj1jqm41n834xh1xcczffrfh9uqlhyd.jpg",
            "priceCount": 1
        },
  "72": {
            "id": "72",
            "price": "12000",
            "weight": "25кг",
            "description": "Используется в качестве умягчителя воды, хелатирующего агента и компонента моющих составов",
            "title": " Хеласин",
            "img": "/upload/iblock/19c/ydj1jqm41n834xh1xcczffrfh9uqlhyd.jpg",
            "priceCount": 1
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Я хочу получить массив объектов, чтобы можно было перебрать с помощью map

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать при помощи функции [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
   var a = {
    "71": {
        "id": "71",
        "price": "12000",
        "weight": "25кг",
        "description": "Используется в качестве умягчителя воды, хелатирующего агента и компонента моющих составов",
        "title": " Хеласин",
        "img": "/upload/iblock/19c/ydj1jqm41n834xh1xcczffrfh9uqlhyd.jpg",
        "priceCount": 1
    },
  "72": {
        "id": "72",
        "price": "12000",
        "weight": "25кг",
        "description": "Используется в качестве умягчителя воды, хелатирующего агента и компонента моющих составов",
        "title": " Хеласин",
        "img": "/upload/iblock/19c/ydj1jqm41n834xh1xcczffrfh9uqlhyd.jpg",
        "priceCount": 1
    }
}

var b = Object.entries(a).map((a) => ( { [a[0]]: a[1] } ))

console.log(b)
```

[Оригинал вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795643/how-to-convert-object-containing-objects-into-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Все что нам нужно сделать - пройтись по значениям внутри каждого объекта внутри нашего главного объекта.

С помощью `for (let key of Object.keys(objt)` пройдемся по ключам родительского объекта, а после залезем в каждый из внутренних объектов при помощи `for (let value of Object.keys(objt[key])` , где `value` - значение, `objt[key]` - вызов внутреннего объекта по ключу.

```js
const objt = {
    "71": {
        "id": "71",
        "price": "12000",
        "weight": "25кг",
        "description": "Используется в качестве умягчителя воды, хелатирующего агента и компонента моющих составов",
        "title": " Хеласин",
        "img": "/upload/iblock/19c/ydj1jqm41n834xh1xcczffrfh9uqlhyd.jpg",
        "priceCount": 1
    },
    "72": {
        "id": "72",
        "price": "12000",
        "weight": "25кг",
        "description": "Используется в качестве умягчителя воды, хелатирующего агента и компонента моющих составов",
        "title": " Хеласин",
        "img": "/upload/iblock/19c/ydj1jqm41n834xh1xcczffrfh9uqlhyd.jpg",
        "priceCount": 1
    }
}

let newarr = []

for (let key of Object.keys(objt)) {
    const innerArr = []
    for (let value of Object.values(objt[key])) {
        innerArr.push(value)
    }
    newarr.push(innerArr)
}

console.log(newarr)
```

Comment: Заметил, мой ответ не соответствует Вашему ожидаемому результату и заданию, однако моим способом можно заполнить массив только значениями каждого объекта создав массив массивов